# NullPointerException after loading an attribute from MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm getting a NullPointerException after an initial method in the constructor of the class is called. That method initializeJdbc() is suppose to fill the field "titles" with names of titles from the Course table in the database. However, I keep getting that exception. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Here is the code below:

```
@Named(value = "courseName")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CourseNameJSfBean {
    private PreparedStatement studentStatement = null;
    private String choice;
    private String[] titles;
    
    public CourseNameJSfBean() {
        initializeJdbc();
    }
    
    private void initializeJdbc() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");
            
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook", "root", "12345");
            
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "select title from Course");
            
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (result.next()) {
                list.add(result.getString(1));
            }
            titles = new String[list.size()];
            list.toArray(titles);
            
            studentStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "select Student.ssn, Student.firstName, Student.mi, " +
                    "Student.lastName, Student.phone, Student.birthDate, Student.street, " +
                    "Student.zipCode, Student.deptId from Student, Enrollement, Course " + 
                    "where Course.title = ? and Student.ssn = Enrollment.ssn and " +
                    "Enrollment.courseId = Course.courseId");   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

// Getters & setters 

public ResultSet getStudents() throws SQLException {
        if (choice == null) {
            if (titles.length == 0)
                return null;
            else 
                studentStatement.setString(1, titles[0]);
        } else {
            studentStatement.setString(1, choice);
        }
        
        return studentStatement.executeQuery();
    }
```

The NullPointerException comes up at the line that says

```
if (titles.length == 0)
```

Here's the exception message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CourseNameJSfBean.getStudents(CourseNameJSfBean.java:71)
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.CourseNameJSfBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getStudents(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: looks like the field `titles` is itself null

Comment: Exactly and so it looks like you need to do some debugging with your IDE's debugger to find out why. Perhaps `initializeJdbc()` is not called before `getStudents(...)`, or perhaps it is called, but on a different reference.

Comment: another possibility from what [Hovercraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) is suggesting, is that the data is different from what you expect.

Comment: @Alex.T Should I initialize `titles` for it to work? If so, how should I do that? Cause I don't know how many names are in the Course table I'm working on. That's why I didn't initialize `titles` ahead. I've tried debugging but whenever I do the `initializeJdbc()` is called first than `getStudents()` but it goes directly to the exception once it's finished called.

Comment: `titles = list.toArray(new String[0]);` should fix the problem.